# Page Transition on WP 7 with Cordova + Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

we developed an small application fpr Windows Phone 7.5.
That application has two differnet screens.(Page A and Page B)

On the first screen(Page A) is an button. If the user hit the button the screen should change from page A to page B.

The Problem is that sometimes the "page transition" works immediatley, sometimes won`t work and sometimes after 4 or 5 seconds.

We use this code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1642653/

And we use:

- Cordova 2.3.0
- jQuery 1.8
- jQuery Mobile 1.2.0

How colud we solve this problem?

best regars,  Sammy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some platforms currently have issues with transitions. We are working on a solution to solve the problem for everyone. If you are experiencing flickers and flashes during or at the end of a transition we suggest the following workaround. Please note that this workaround should be throughly tested on the target platform before deployment. This workaround is known to cause performance issues, and browser crashes on some platforms especially Android.

Add the following code to your custom css.

```
.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

Source: [JQuery Page transitions](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)

**UPDATE:** You have missed to close two `</div>`. I have tested your code on Chrome (PC) it is working flawlessly. It might be a browser issue.